# ClassNotFoundException for android.view.Space when running application

Tags: android, android-layout, classnotfoundexception

I'm having an issue running my application when certain elements exist in the layout of my activity.  I have the following layout, and I have issue when I include the "Space" element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:text="@string/foursquare" />

<Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/foursquare_button"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:text="@string/yelp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_weight="0.18" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The error I get is this:

> > 11-26 11:14:09.875: E/AndroidRuntime(10485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     ...
> >     11-26 11:14:09.875: E/AndroidRuntime(10485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infoit.nfc.activity/com.infoit.nfc.activity.ViewTag}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class Space
> >     ...
> >     11-26 11:14:09.875: E/AndroidRuntime(10485): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class Space
> >     ...
> >     11-26 11:14:09.875: E/AndroidRuntime(10485): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Space in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.infoit.nfc.activity-2.apk]
> >     ...

If I remove the Space element everything is peachy keen.  Somehow it's not able to find the Space class even though I thought defining the xmlns would solve the issue.  I feel this is something simple, but I am missing it.

Comment: Do you use API 14? SDK 14 is required by space layout

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I was developing on API 14, but deployed it to a Gingerbread phone.  Hence, this probably wouldn't give the error if I were on a proper Ice Cream Sandwich phone.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The xml file needs to refer to existing widgets either defined by the platform or by your own project, and `Space` is not a standard Android widget. Try replacing it with `View` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  For my own edification, what describes a standard Android widget?  I got this Space element by dragging and dropping from the layout component palette, I would have thought anything there would be standard.

Comment: As Style said, `Space` was introduced in Ice Cream Sandwich. `View` has been there since the being of (Android) time :)

Comment: Space class is available in the support library v4 as a public class, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Space.html

Comment: also repleace using androix lib, Try androidx.legacy.widget.Space

Answer (score 14):

Using the `View` component in place of `Space` might work.

But I would try to keep `Space`, but using the following:

```
<android.widget.Space …>
```

It tends to work more reliably than when it worked with `<Space …>`.

Another option is using the legacy version:

```
<androidx.legacy.widget.Space …>
```

Answer (score 7):

Space was introduced in API 14 but it's also available from android support v7:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="12dp"/>
```

By the way:

- use `dp` instead of `px`
- no need of secify the `android:layout_height` in a vertical `LinearLayout` with weight

Comment: what is min API for `android.support.v7.widget.Space`, not working on API10

Comment: Space class is now working under `android.support.v4` package, use this reference `android.support.v4.Space`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers didn't work for me. Finally, I changed it to v4 like this:

```
android.support.v4.widget.Space
```

and it worked fine.

Class reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/Space.html